# TPanel - was/is BevelXXXX value bvSpace implemented?

Tags: delphi, vcl

VCL's `TPanel` has two properties, `BevelInner` and `BevelOuter`. One of the possible values is `bvSpace` which is said to reserve screen space but to avoid rendering pseudo-3D look.

> bvSpace - The bevel appears as a space if its kind is not bkTile. Otherwise, the bevel appears raised.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TPanelBevel

However, in practice, I have never seen this ever work, there was never any difference between `bvSpace` and `bvRaised`. Granted, I do not remember Delphi 2, which I only used for a few short months a looong time ago.

Looking at the sources of Delphi 5 (1999), XE2, and XE4, the related code is `ExtCtrls.pas` or `Vcl.ExtCtrls.pas`.

```
procedure TCustomPanel.Paint;
  ...
  procedure AdjustColors(Bevel: TPanelBevel);
  begin
    TopColor := BaseTopColor;
    if Bevel = bvLowered then
      TopColor := BaseBottomColor;
    BottomColor := BaseBottomColor;
    if Bevel = bvLowered then
      BottomColor := BaseTopColor;
  end;

begin
  ...
  if BevelOuter <> bvNone then
  begin
    AdjustColors(BevelOuter);
    Frame3D(Canvas, Rect, TopColor, BottomColor, BevelWidth);
  end;
  ...
  if BevelInner <> bvNone then
  begin
    AdjustColors(BevelInner);
    Frame3D(Canvas, Rect, TopColor, BottomColor, BevelWidth);
  end;
```

The differences between D5, XE2 and XE4 are miniscule there. The code clearly and totally ignores the existence of any values but `bvNone` and `bvLowered` - all other values are considered to be the same. IOW, code-wise, there is no such value as `bvSpace`, which everyone can see in the Form Designer.

*Granted, such a look can easily be **simulated** by using `BorderWidth` > 0  and `BorderKind` = bkNone.*

What I wonder is if this was an intentional (and crude) decision to remove functionality that failed to be accounted for in documentation? Or was it a failed implementation that somehow was universally overlooked for decades?

Can people having vast VCL versions on their shelf look at `procedure TCustomPanel.Paint;` implementations in Delphi 1.0/2.0 and in some later Delphi XE 10.x - is it all the same? Or maybe this value was used only in the long past? Or maybe it recently got implemented finally?

UPD. Peeped into the sources of Delphi XE10.1 (18.0) - still the same gap. Can someone with access to their new non-public bug-tracker register bug report there?

Comment: The Delphi 4 documentation doesn't mention `bvSpace` at all.

Comment: I searched the entire VCL sources of v5 and v6, and the *only* mention of `bvSpace` anywhere is in the declaration of `TBevelCut` (which `TPanelBevel` is an alias of), nowhere else.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Do you by chance have Kylix 1 sources? i had a *very* exotic idea esterday, that *maybe* it was somehow born us prepping Delphi for CLX cross-compatibility, and there were some preliminary changes in D5 already. As an exotic idea, they could introduce it for the future copatubulity with Qt, and so it made it to documentation, but since VCL did not need it and Qt afair was shortlived they did never implement it actually. Yes, sounds crazy, but such an obvious glaring hole in VCL going unnoticed for 22 years is no less crazy :-) And.. Maybe some XE 10.xxx had it finally done?

Comment: @Arioch'The Kylix was introduced in Delphi/C++Builder 6, so yes, I searched that code as well. But the declaration of `bvSpace` predates Kylix. Like you said, maybe it was related to a feature that was never fully realized. That would make sense. I have a few more versions of source code after v6 that I can check, but I doubt I'll find anything.

Comment: @RemyLebeau *introduced* as a ready solution, yes. But preparations for new product take years.  I don't remember details, but back then i saw some D5 v D4 changes that made sense retroactively as move to cross-platform compilations. And while Kylix share a lot it is not quite D6. But i agree this was a queer desperate idea with no consistent scenario to back it. There is no point indeed to look in between Delphi 5 and Delphi XE4 cause they have mostly identical code lacking the feature. It might have some sense to check before (Andreas checked D4 docs but not code) or later (XE 10.x).

Comment: @Arioch'The I only have the source code for D/CB 5..XE3.